# Django model that stores multiple other models that store multiple other models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am learning Django so this is all very new to me. What I am trying to create is a bit of functionality in my admin panel that will allow me to create a layout like this.

```
Test
-Event1
--Property1
--Property2
--Property3
--Property4
-Event2
--Property1a
--Property2b
--Property3c
--Property4d
-Event3
--Property1aa
--Property2bb
--Property3cc
--Property4dd
-Event4
--Property1aaa
--Property2bbb
--Property3ccc
--Property4ddd
```

I want to have multiple tests. My current model setup looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ("string", "string"),
    ("integer", "integer"),
    ("array", "array"),
    ("boolean", "boolean")
)

class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Test'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tests'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    test_id = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Event'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Events'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    property_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    expected_value = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Property'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Properties'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ['name', 'description']
```

I have my admin panel setup so that I can create multiple properties. But then when I go to the "Events" section in my admin panel I can only create events. I want to be able to pick the properties and add them to my event. Then I want to be able to go to the Test page and add the events to it.

A good example of what I am trying to create is a replica of this: http://jsonparser.tools/tests.php

Comment: do you want to set  tasks as foreign key of event and event as foreign key of properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should define foreign keys for events and properties:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ("string", "string"),
    ("integer", "integer"),
    ("array", "array"),
    ("boolean", "boolean")
)

class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Test'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tests'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Event'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Events'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Property(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    property_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    expected_value = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Property'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Properties'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ['name', 'description']
```

this should solve your problem if not let me know happy to help.

Comment: I get this when trying to migrate.. You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'event' to property without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).

Comment: while migrating did you requested to set default values? you should set some value because you have some field already existing in the task table while migrating exiting event record get null field at event field and event field must have some value so provide some value of the previously added task

Comment: Yeah that was an issue. I just cleaned out my db and started from scratch since I had nothing.

Comment: Yeah this seemed to have worked. Now I need to work on setting up some other things that I am running into issues with. I will work on them until i get stuck. Thank you!